# How to build JQuery and Bootstrap using Webpack without node modules?

Tags: webpack

I need use the jQuery and Bootstrap, but I will not use big part of these libraries' code. I want to put scripts `jquery.js` and `bootstrap.bundle.js` to project folder, delete unused code from them and then build and minify by Webpack. I try:

```js
import "jquery.js";
import "bootstrap.bundle.js"
```

But webpack gives error `Can't resolve 'jquery'`.

I tried use ProvidePlugin, but it didn't help:

```js
plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            jquery: "./jquery.js",
        })
    ],
```

I also tried add externals `"jquery": "window.jQuery"`, it provides to build bundle, but I have JS error `Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery. jQuery must be included before Bootstrap's JavaScript`. In result bundle libraries order is `bootstrap, jquery` (incorrect order).

Also I tried raw-loader, but it didn't help too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted ProvidePlugin usage, putted jquery and bootstrap to `lib` folder and set `resolve` option:

```js
resolve: {
        modules: [
            "lib"
        ]
},
```